# where can I get a copy of Boot Configuration Data?

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot, uefi, gpt, efi

Within the context of UEFI booting on Windows, Wikipedia redirects "Windows Boot Manager" to the [Windows Vista Startup Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista_startup_process):

> Boot Configuration Data are stored in a data file that has the same
>   format as the Windows Registry hives and is eventually mounted at
>   registry key [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\BCD00000][3] (with restricted
>   permissions[4]). For UEFI boot, the file is located at
>   \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD on the EFI System Partition. For traditional
>   BIOS boot, the file is at \boot\BCD on the active partition.[5]

For UEFI dual-booting with Linux, I'll backup the BCD file.  Out of curiosity, can this file be downloaded from Microsoft directly?